# Is it possible for a REST Client and Server to send/receive generic lists of custom classes?

Tags: c#, rest, client-server, xml-serialization, generic-list

I am refactoring a legacy pair of apps which send and receive XML files. I would prefer that the server pass back a generic list of a custom class (both client and server will have to be synchronized with any changes to these custom classes). IOW, I want to call the server from the client like so:

```
List<Departments> depts = fileXfer.FetchDepartmentData(String.Format("{0}/FetchDepartments", HHSConsts.BASE_REST_URL));
```

Where "Departments" is a custom class that both the client and server will see as their own. Is this possible? Does the REST infrastructure support sending/passing lists of custom classes?

Would it be better to just pass back the XML files, or a String, or a List, or convert the XML to json, or...???

### UPDATE

So (based on the link provided by Avijit) is this the way to do it:

Instead of calling the REST method from the client this way:

```
List<Departments> siteMappings = fileXfer.FetchDepartments(String.Format("{0}/FetchDepartments", HHSConsts.BASE_REST_URL));
```

...and returning a generic list of Departments from the server, do it this  way:

Client code:

```
 ArrayList depts = fileXfer.FetchDepartments(String.Format("{0}/FetchDepartments", HHSConsts.BASE_REST_URL));
 // parse the ArrayList back into a generic list of Departments
```

Server code:

```
 // get the data and put it into a generic list, then:
 ArrayList blandifiedDepts = new ArrayList();
 foreach (Department dept in List<Departments>)
 {
     blandifiedDepts.Add(dept);
 }
 return blandifiedDepts;
```

Does this make good sense?

### UPDATE 2

So this is my idea: the server returns all the generic lists as ArrayList, and I handle them this way on the client side:

```
    ArrayList arrList = _fileXfer.FetchSiteMappings(String.Format("{0}/FetchSiteMappings", HHSConsts.BASE_REST_URL));
    List<SiteMapping> siteMappings = ConvertArrayListToSiteMappingList(arrList);
    _hhsdbutils.SaveSiteMappingData(siteMappings);

private static List<SiteMapping> ConvertArrayListToSiteMappingList(ArrayList arrList)
{
    List<SiteMapping> siteMappingList = new List<SiteMapping>();
    foreach (object arr in arrList)
    {
        SiteMapping sm;
        var mapping = arr as SiteMapping;
        if (mapping != null)
        {
            sm = mapping;
        }
        else continue;
        siteMappingList.Add(sm);
    }
    return siteMappingList;
}
```

Any objections/constructive critiques (hint: mute close votes are not constructive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done. You can refer this http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/F2aL081113-Passing-multiple-complex-type-parameters-to-ASP.NET-Web-API.html